# Как узнать имя и путь к файлу через приложение?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Когда файл открывается с помощью приложения, приложение должно определить полный путь к файлу и имя файла. Затем файл копируется по нужному пути. И вставляется в папку, оставляя оригинальное имя файла и его расширение.

Например:

```
копируем > полный путь к файлу
вставляем > нужный путь > оригинальное имя файла и его расширение + свое расширение
Скопированный файл должен получить такое имя: orig-file-name.txt.my
```

Код (с ошибками, но как пример):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string oldFilePath = (Path.GetFullPath(args[0])); // приводит к ошибке границ массива
        string newFilePath = (Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\AppName\\Copy\\new.txt"));
        File.Copy(oldFilePath, newFilePath, true);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: *приводит к ошибке границ массива* — а как запускаете-то?

Comment: Берется файл (test.txt), переносится на приложение, приложение запускается. Файл должен копироваться в указанную папку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения списка аргументов используйте:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

В args[0] передается путь к исполняемому файлу, в остальных элементах массива будут пути к выделенным и перетащенным файлам.

Копирование файла:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length > 1)
        {
            string filePath = args[1];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string newFileName = String.Format("{0}.my", fileName);
            string dstPath = @"D:\music\" + newFileName;
            File.Copy(filePath, dstPath, true);
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Идеальный вариант. Пришлось сократить `args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` чтобы другой код выполнился, т.к. использовался `static void Main(string[] args)`